# How to use getLoggerPlugin() in @aws-sdk/middleware-logger?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-sdk-js-v3

I see this function is used at many places in the v3 clients, For example [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/7a374640980e86f1ee70527d596b7ccb9de475f1/clients/client-acm/src/ACMClient.ts#L345) is there any proper usage documents?